# Is there a more emphatic version of posse?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, nuance, passage-request

If I want to say "I can" in Latin, I will usually use *posse*.
But what if I want something stronger and more emphatic, like "I am capable of", "I am able to", or similar?
I am not aware of a Latin idiom that would mean more or less the same as *posse* but have more gravity.
Are there **classical attestations** of an "emphatic *posse*" that I could mimic?

Comment: I kind of understand where you're coming from, but it would be interesting if you could provide a few sentence where *posse* won't do. Perhaps a Roman would use a different construction altogether.

Comment: Not sure if I get the sense of the question, but in Church Latin you have [_habilis esse ad_](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22habilis+est+ad%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) + (noun or verb-ndum): _habilis est ad bonum_, _habilis es ad faciendum_ whatever. I tried to look it up on Perseus for instances in Classical Latin, but I only found clues, nothing conclusive.

Comment: @Cerberus If someone asks whether I can do something, "I can do that" sounds like a throwaway comment which doesn't even imply that I'm paying attention, whereas "I am capable of that" sounds way more emphatic and tells that I have the capability to do the thing. Of course, one can always use a plain "I can" (or a plain *posse*), but sometimes I would like to have some more gravity to it; it is a matter of nuance. It's indeed possible that the Romans would use something entirely different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One sometimes finds *valere* + infinitive used with the sense of 'to have the ability or power to' (*OLD* definition 6). I'm not sure it really has more gravity than *posse*; at any rate, I tend to think that the mere fact that it's being used instead of the more obvious *posse* makes it somewhat 'marked' in the sentence.

Comment: I have accepted this as the bets answer so far. I have a faint feeling that there is something better out there that what has been suggested here, but perhaps this is indeed all there is to it.

Answer (score 3):

Your only real option is to use word placement, that is to put the [posse] form in an unusual position in the sentence. It's quite a normal way of emphasising : for example, where *magnum pondus tollere potest* simply indicates the ability to lift a large weight, *potest magnum pondus tollere* is a stronger declaration of it.

Otherwise, there are such phrases as *nequeo quin …*, 'I can't do other than …*, to suggest you can do something, but only because you have no alternative (this may get fairly close, but it isn't really what you want), and *haud dubitandum erat quin possem ….*, 'there was no doubting but that I was able to … ', which might serve well enough.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the Latin proverb often attributed to Hannibal when he attempted to cross the Alps: *viam aut inveniam aut faciam* (I shall either find a way or make one) which although not using *posse* may be a suitable replacement for 'I can' depending on the context.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a welcome reminder, as it is often better to use a completely different expression when emphasis is needed. I was looking for more general (and classically attested) emphatic versions of *posse* so I won't accept this one, but it certainly deserves my upvote.